# devise: link_to user edit page using current_user.first_name as label

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, erb

How can I combine:

```
<%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_registration_path %>
<%= link_to do %> <strong><%= current_user.first_name %></strong><% end %>
```

Such that I replace the "Profile" with the current users first name?

In effect, when the user clicks their name, they should go to their user profile page in edit action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try to do it in one line like

```
<%= link_to current_user.first_name, edit_user_registration_path %>
```

but if you want to use a block then

```
<%= link_to edit_user_registration_path do %>                     
  <strong><%= current_user.first_name %></strong>
<% end %>
```